# Iteration through 2 lists in paralell using the same index

Tags: python, list, loops

I am attempting to iterate through the list index of two lists in parallel in order to append the range between the ith number in the first list and the ith number in the second list to a new variable, each range in its own list. I do not want to include the first number in the range so for the first iteration the output would be `[2,3]`The lists are as follows:

```
def_idx = [1,13,23]
return_id = [3,14,25]
line_idx = []`
```

The desired output of `line_idx` would be as follows:
`line_idx = [[2, 3], [14], [24, 25]]`

My attempt at this has not worked due to having too many lists:

```
line_idx = []
for i, j in enumerate(def_idx):
    line_idx.append([list(range(j + 1, return_idx[i] + 1))])
```

Any help would be appreciated and if the question is not clear then I am very happy to give further explanation.

Comment: are both your lists always the same length?

Comment: Yes they are always the same

Comment: then zip is the way to go @mamun has given a good example

Comment: I don’t understand your attempted solution, are you familiar with `range()`?

Comment: Question has been answered below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
In [4]: line_idx = [list(range(i + 1, j + 1)) for i, j in zip(def_idx, return_idx)]

In [5]: line_idx
Out[5]: [[2, 3], [14], [24, 25]]
```

Without `zip` as requested by the op:

```
In [10]: line_idx = [list(range(j + 1, return_idx[i] + 1)) for i, j in enumerate
...: (def_idx)]

In [11]: line_idx
Out[11]: [[2, 3], [14], [24, 25]]
```

Another low level language where arrays are not iterable like version:

```
In [12]: line_idx = [list(range(def_idx[i] + 1, return_idx[i] + 1)) for i in ran
...: ge(len(def_idx))]

In [13]: line_idx
Out[13]: [[2, 3], [14], [24, 25]]
```

Comment: need a +1 on i and j as the doesnt want the start num but wants to include the end num

Comment: I added a version without the zip